# How do i convert a string array into json jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, django

Im using Django, the view that returns json object, has the next code:

```
def searchTourDBEsp_view(request):
    print 'llamamos search ESP'
    dataTourEsp = TourEsp.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM appMain_tour where idTour=1')
    dataTourEspSer = serializers.serialize("json",dataTourEsp)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(dataTourEspSer),content_type='application/json')
```

as you can see i have to make a serialization to the database consult.

In my template i need to have access to the data that is returned.

```
$.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url:  '{% url "url_searchTourEsp"%}',
         data: data1,             
         success: function(jsonAjaxResult){  
                  console.log("Ajax ok");
                  console.log("nombre");
                  console.log(jsonAjaxResult);   
                  console.log(jsonAjaxResult[0]);  
                                },
                  error: function(data){
                   alert("Got an error, Pleas conctact the Administrator");
                   alert(data);
            }
});
```

The jsonAjaxResult object has all the information that i need, but it is an array of string.
The content of jsonAjaxResult is the follow

```
[{
"fields":
 {
 "Monday": true, 
 "restrictions": "No kids",
 "name": "Yate Mar", 

 }, 
 "model": "appMain.touresp", 
 "pk": 1
 }]
```

and the only way to have access to the data is typing

```
console.log(jsonAjaxResult[0]);
```

that has as result `[`

does someone know how to have access to the information like:

```
jsonAjaxResult['restrictions'];
```

but if i type this, the result is `undefined`

Comment: `jsonAjaxResult[0]['restrictions']` You need to iterate over the array and query the restriction of each element.

Comment: if i write console.log(jsonAjaxResult[0]['restrictions']);

the result is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reference a particular index in an array, the syntax is `array[index]`. To reference an object's property, the syntax is `object.property` or `object["property"]`. Since your data structure involves nested objects within an array, simply use the appropriate syntax for referencing the value at each layer.

In this case, your top-level data type is an array. That array contains an object with a property named `fields`. The value of that property is, in turn, another object that has its own property named `restrictions`. You have to reference each of these from the top-down.

```
var data = [
    {
        "fields": {
            "Monday": true, 
            "restrictions": "No kids",
            "name": "Yate Mar",
        }, 
        "model": "appMain.touresp", 
        "pk": 1
    }
];
```

To get the value for the `restrictions` property, do the following: `data[0].fields.restrictions`.

If your array has multiple values and you wish to get the `restrictions` for each one, iterate over the array and substitute the `0` with your array index variable. That is:

```
for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].fields.restrictions);
}
```

---

**EDIT**: You'll have to decode your JSON string into an array before doing this. Use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) for that:

```
JSON.parse(jsonAjaxResult)[0].fields.restrictions
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, i did what you tould me, but the next error shows up :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'restrictions' of undefined

The jsonAjaxResult is an array of String because if i type jsonAjaxResult[0] the result is '[' and if you iterate over that array it shows '{' , '"' , 'f' , 'i' , 'e' , ........

Comment: @Matvi That seems to suggest the actual structure of the data is a little different than what you've posted. Can you do a `console.log(jsonAjaxResult)` and post what gets logged to the console? It could be that the data was not properly JSON-serialized.

Comment: @Matvi Oh got it. You don't have an array of strings. You just have a single string, because your data hasn't been decoded and it's wrapped as a string. You'll have to parse the JSON before accessing the data. See update above.